# Laravel-Vue publishing components which should be protected by authentication

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, routes, vuejs2

I am relatively new to Vue and started to build an SPA with Authentication and the Laravel Framework in the background. To achieve that I followed this tutorial:

https://codeburst.io/api-authentication-in-laravel-vue-spa-using-jwt-auth-d8251b3632e0

The auth is working perfectly fine. But what bugs my now is that routes/components which are protected with auth are also bundled in my `app.js` and are fully readable for everyone who is able to use the dev console.

Example

These are my routes:

```
export default new VueRouter({
routes: [
    {
        path: '/',
        redirect: '/login',
    },
    {
        path: '/login',
        name: 'login',
        component: AuthLogin,
        meta: {
            auth: false
        },
    },
    {
        path: '/order',
        name: 'order',
        component: OrderPage,
        meta: {
            auth: true
        },
    },
  ]
});
```

So `/order` and the corresponding component `OrderPage` ist protected by auth.
`OrderPage`:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Order Page
  </div>
</template>
```

However the component `OrderPage` is readable in `app.js` in public directory. I can just search for the content "Order Page" and read it which is in my opinion not the goal of auth.

Is there a way to "isolate" the protected components and only export/bundle them when the auth is passed? Am I missing something?

Comment: You likely aren't bundling the javascript on the fly... You're transpiling and bundling long before the client visits your site, so no you shouldn't bundle when auth is passed.   You could isolate code to a specific javascript file, there's no reason why you need to have everything bundled in the same app.js file.  However, there's really no point from a security standpoint.  Client side code should never contain anything sensitive and minified code should be incredibly hard to decipher.  All authorizations should be performed on the server.

Comment: In production, your JS will get minified, which will make it pretty much non-readable. Shouldn't have anything secret in there - no API keys etc. - but it'll be well protected against casual "I wonder what that does".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Bundling based on Auth**
You likely aren't bundling the javascript on the fly... You're transpiling and bundling long before the client visits your site, so no you shouldn't bundle when auth is passed. Bundling, transpiling, and minifying can be pretty resource intensive processes.

**Isolation for Security**
You could isolate code to a specific javascript file, there's no reason why you need to have everything bundled in the same app.js file.  Laravel Mix can produce multiple bundles based on your configuration.

However, there's really no point from a security standpoint since client side code should **never** contain anything sensitive and all authorizations for actions should be performed on the server.

**Production Readability**
If you're worried about someone reading the client side code,  minified javascript is incredibly hard to decipher since it's shrunk down and obfuscated.  Production javascript should always be minified without source maps.